# Empty space to the right

Tags: html, css, wordpress

There is an empty space to the right of the website and as a result there is a horizotnal scroll bar at the bottom. I could not find the reason why this is happening. I know I could just disable that scroll bar in css, but I would prefer more elegant solution that would acutally fix the issue.

Here is the url to the website: http://jeziernia.zamojskolubaczowska.pl/

I realized that it's the problem with elementor menu. Is it possible to make it unfold in such a way that it is always within the screen?
[image: problem]

Comment: Please add your code ! ;-)

Comment: Add your code here to check

Answer (score 0):

Change the breakpoint for your grid